# Seperate record from one column into 2 columns in Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have column address that looks like this:

```
address
--------------
Virginia Ave
Baker Ave
Elm Road
.....
```

I need to separate each record into 2 columns.First column will hold street name and 2nd column is street abbreviation so it will look like this:

```
StreetName          StreetAbbr
-----------       -----------
Virginia             Ave
Baker                Ave
Elm                 Road
```

What is the easiest and most efficient(I have huge number of records)
to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: use regular expresions, or substr pattern matching.  try some things, and come back when you are close but still can't figure it out.

Comment: This is part of the *address normalization problem*, which at first glance seems reasonable to approach with a bunch of hand-written regex. In practice it's actually really quite hard to do well, so if you need more general address normalisation consider looking into one of the existing products in the area.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string will be **StreetName StreetAbbr**, the following sql code maybe be you useful, i'm not sure that is the most effectively, but works:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO TEST(ADDRESS) VALUES('Virginia Ave');
INSERT INTO TEST(ADDRESS) VALUES('Baker Ave');
INSERT INTO TEST(ADDRESS) VALUES('Elm Road');

SELECT 
(string_to_array(ADDRESS, ' '))[1] AS StreetName,
(string_to_array(ADDRESS, ' '))[2] AS StreetAbbr
FROM TEST;
```

Here is the [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e8f76/6) with the example. You can also do this with regular expressions or string simple functions (please see this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)). Anyway before doing all this, you would have in mind the **normalization**.

Comment: it gets more complicated with real world data: i.e. `INSERT INTO TEST(ADDRESS) VALUES('Martin Luther King Jr. Way');`

Comment: Then in that case, is much more complex, would have to identify the pattern to separate the string. His example seemed to be something simpler.

Comment: @house9 Yes,get more complicated with two or more words street name.I guess that could be solved with starting from the end of the string and then search for the space.Maybe with rtrim(string text [, characters text])?